# How can I replace this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following element:

```
<span data-valmsg-for="Company.People[0].Name" />
```

What I would like to do, is take the 'data-valmsg-for' attribute and format it to look like this:

```
var idToLocate = "Company.People_0__Name";
```

How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the attribute value into a javascript variable, jQuery is not required.  You can  simply do a replace operation on it to convert it to the form you want:

```
var str = "Company.People[0].Name";
var idToLocate = str.replace(/\[(\d+)\]\./,"_$1__");
// idToLocate will now be "Company.People_0__Name"
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XYwbL/.

Comment: How would I account for all numerical values?  0 was just my example but I may have 0-many.  Probably anything under 1000 realistically.

Comment: @Beavis - I modified my answer to work for any numeric value in the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var idToLocate = $('span').attr('data-valmsg-for').replace('[', '_').replace('].', '__');
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UbcPH/ Only improvement would be a more unique selector to ensure that it works outside of the example. http://jsfiddle.net/UbcPH/1/ `$('span[data-valmsg-for^=\'Company.People\']').attr('data-valmsg-for').replace('[', '_').replace('].', '__');`

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it doesn't extract the numerical value, which can be 0+.  How would I do that?

Comment: @Beavis - You don't have to worry about that, it will retain that number in the modified string.

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right, sorry about that.  I'd mark this as answered too if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Get the attribute with `$('span').attr('data-valmsg-for')` and set it with `$('span').attr('data-valmsg-for', value)`.